# 1+2+3+4+...+n = -1/12?

Tags: popularity-contest

Today, [Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/user/numberphile) posted [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-I6XTVZXww) where it's stated that `1+2+3+4+...+n = -1/12`.

While this isn't really new (several ways to prove that have been found, you can look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39802/why-does-123-dots-1-over-12/39811#39811) for further informations), this leads us to our question!

Your goal is to write a function that returns **-0.083333** (feel free to stop at **-0.083** if you wish), which is -1/12.

Be original, since this is a [popularity-contest](/questions/tagged/popularity-contest)!

Most upvoted answer in 2 weeks wins this.

Comment: I don't understand, does this mean that infinity is -1/12?

Comment: No, but there are several mathematic methods to calculate this value as the result of that sum. Read the link I gave for more informations about that, this would be off-topic here I guess! :)

Comment: These wikipedia articles seem relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation#Sum_of_divergent_series http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%C2%B7_%C2%B7_%C2%B7#Summability

Answer (score 3):

The [Riemann Zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) is defined as ζ(s) = Sum(n<sup>-s</sup>) where you sum from n=1 to n=infinity.  Hence ζ(-1) = Sum(n) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... to infinity.

Now [scipy defines zetac](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.zetac.html) to be `sum(k**(-x), k=2..inf)` (that is the zeta function with the first term removed).

Hence in python

```
>>> import scipy.special
>>> print 1+scipy.special.zetac(-1)
-0.0833333333333
```

essentially calculates the infinite sum 1+2+3+4+... to give -1/12.

Answer (score 2):

### J

This is quite short, but I hope you think it's sweet:

```
(%&13@<:^:_)0
```

I'm relying on the fact that a negative twelfth is -0.1111111... in base thirteen. This function takes its argument, decrements it, and divides by 13 (a right-shift in base 13). It does this until the value converges to -1/12. To see how the base 13 stuff fits in, you might want to imagine the 13 being changed to a 10. The function would then converge at decimal -0.111111... = -1/9.

Answer (score 2):

## PowerShell (and probably a polyglot)

I know this isn't code-golf, but since no other parameters are really defined for the challenge except:

> Your goal is to write a function that returns -0.083333 (feel free to stop at -0.083 if you wish), which is -1/12.

I have a really hard time justifying doing anything other than:

```
-1/12
```

This outputs:

```
-0.0833333333333333
```